# Magento cash on delivery payment

Tags: magento, payment

Can I disable the cash on delivery payment option when I got for example order with a price higher than 150 $ ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm sorry, i will use magento.stackexchange next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to system > configuration > payment method > cash on delivery

you can see  Minimum order total & Maximum order total.

you can keep 150 in Maximum order total field , so its going to restrict COD payment method for more than that value